# Laravel. Путь к файлу в папке storage

Tags: laravel, link, storage

Файлы хранятся в директории `storage/app/files`
Как к ним обратится через asset ?
`asset('storage')` - это путь к `storage/app/public`
Но в данном случае нужно обращаться именно к `storage/app/files`

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = storage_path('app/files');
```

Можно сделать так

Comment: В таком случае у меня пусть будет типа W:/domains/site/storage/app/files/file.pdf И по нему не возвращает файл. В случае с asset('storage/file.pdf') Хоть и файл будет хранится в storage/app/public/file.pdf оно будет его возвращать но по пути без app/public ( storage/file.pdf ) . Здесь кажется нужно делать какие-то настройки для каталога files....

Comment: ну да, когда выполняешь команду php artisan storage:link, то из public появляется ссылка на storage и по умолчанию настройки прописаны в config -> filesystems. Попробуйте там поменять

Answer (score 1):

В файл filesystems добавил линки

```
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('files') => storage_path('app/files'),
    ],
```

И запустил снова php artisan `storage:link`
Теперь к файлам могу обращаться так: `asset('/files/..')`